# how can We pass id in url using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Code:

```
 <script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#university_name').autocomplete({
      source: 'autocomplete.php',
      minLength: 2,
      select: function(event, ui) {
        var x = ui.item.value;

        x = encodeURIComponent(x);
        location.href = "university_page.php?university_name=" + x + "&university_id=" + x;
        return false;
      }
    });
  }); < /script>
```

autocomplete.php

```
<?php
    include('conn.php');
    $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM all_university WHERE university_name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY university_name ASC");
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
      $data[] = $row['university_name'];
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

how can I pass id in url still when I search in textbox field url have `university_page.php?university_name=xyz`

but I want

`university_page.php?university_name=xyz&university_id=1 ?`

Thank you

Comment: You can simply use jquery
$.get("demo_test.asp", function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    }); see at http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_get.asp

Comment: will you please eleborate ?

Comment: I think some problem in your question description.you mention university_page.php page in jquery and php page is autocomplete.php.

Answer (score 0):

For Jquery Request Try This

```
var get_url = "<baseurl>/autocomplete.php?university_name="+x;
    $.get(get_url, function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

requested file is : autocomplete.php
you must handle uni name by

```
$_GET['university_name']
```